# java parseInt exceptions not being caught

Tags: java, validation, loops, error-handling

I'm trying to catch all exceptions to a parseInt request with the same response, so if the string does not parse to an int, it performs the code under catch.  This would make a simple validation loop, asking them to try again each time they try to leave the field without having entered a valid int.  Right now it will throw exceptions in the system console but not return my pre-configured error message and run its associated code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    //draw and show the GUI
    JFrame GUI = new JFrame();
    GUI.setTitle("New Provider Interface");
    GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final JTextField textID = new JTextField("providerID ", 20);
    final JTextField textName = new JTextField("Provider Name ", 20);
    FocusGrabber fgID = new FocusGrabber(textID);
    GUI.add(textID);
    GUI.add(textName);
    GUI.pack();
    GUI.setVisible(true);
} 
    textID.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){ @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {/* */}
        @Override public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                if (!e.isTemporary()) {
                String  checkID = textID.getText();
                Boolean validID = false;
                if (checkID.isEmpty()){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainFrame, "Please enter a valid ID."); fgID.run();}
                else while (validID = false){try {
                        String sID = textID.getText();
                        int iID = Integer.parseInt(sID);
                    }catch (Exception e1){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainFrame, checkID + "is not a valid ID. Please try again.");
                        fgID.run();
                    }finally {validID= true;}
    }    }    }    }    );
```

Comment: Use JSpinner, JFormattedTextField and/or InputVerifier to make your easier

Comment: A InputVerifier could be used to not only verify the content of your field, but restrict from loosing focus auotomatically

Comment: Your while loop is incredibly dangerous and could result in causing your program to hang

Comment: This is not a SSCCE. We can't copy/paste/compile and execute the code. We don't have access to the FocusGrabber class. That class is irrelevant to the stated question. A SSCCE is code you have compiled yourself to verify it demonstrates the problem you are asking about. Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most are correct, but not all of them. Be consistent.

Comment: thanks for the case tip, I suspected that was the case but lowercase looked wrong so I waited to see if anyone said what I was thinking or not.

Answer (score 0):

The code in `finally` will [always](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) be run, even if there is an `Exception`.

Comment: i think it will be better to exand it more : finally is used when - you want to close an connection , say file ,database irrespective of how bad the code crashed you need somethings to be handelled in a graceful - limit the loss

Comment: removed 'finally' , no change in program behavior.

Comment: What you need is a way to know if there have been an `Exception`. You can do that by introducing a `boolean parseSucceed` initialized to `false` and you put to `true` after the `parseInt`. So after your catch you can do `if(parseSucceed) validID = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of code throwing exception or not finally block will be executed.
For the above program when valid ID is given first time then exception will not throw but finally block will be executed then validId is set to true. On the second call  where invalid ID is been passed but since validId is true while loop will be ignored. Check the a code by passing  invalid ID in the first instance to check any Exception is being caught or not.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is, the `finally` block will always be executed, which is allowing your loop to exit, which is lucky for.

Take a closer look at [try-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) and [try-finally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) for more details

Another problem is, you're using `validID = false` as your exit condition for your `while loop`, which is an assignment, so your exit condition is always `false` and the `while-loop` will never execute

The `while-loop` would otherwise cause your program to hang, as it would be exited within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread which is used to monitor for use inputs and paint requests.

Instead, you should consider using a `InputVerifier`, which would allow you to valid the value of the field before it was about to lose focus and, if you wanted do, prevent the field from loosing focus until it was valid

See [How to validate input](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) for more details

I'd also recommend that you take a look at `JSpinner` and `JFormattedTextField`